# asymptotic limit of exponential function

Tags: calculus, limits

> > What is the limit of following exponential function
> >
> > $e^{\dot\imath k} $ 
> >     when $k_{R}\rightarrow -\infty$ and $k_{R}\rightarrow \infty$?
> >
> > where $k_{R}$ means real part of $k$.

In the book,
\begin{equation}
r=\frac{g_{1}+g_{2}}{1+f_{1}+f_{2}},  \quad (1)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
&& g_{1}=e^{\eta_{1}+\eta_{2}}, \\
&& g_{2} = a_{12\bar{1}}e^{\eta_{1}+\bar{\eta}_{1}+\eta_{2}}+
a_{12\bar{2}}e^{\eta_{1}+\bar{\eta}_{2}+\eta_{2}}, \\
&& f_{1}  = a_{1\bar{1}}e^{\eta_{1}+\bar{\eta}_{1}} +
a_{1\bar{2}}e^{\eta_{1}+\bar{\eta}_{2}} +
a_{2\bar{1}}e^{\eta_{2}+\bar{\eta}_{1}} +
a_{2\bar{2}}e^{\eta_{2}+\bar{\eta}_{2}}, \\
&& f_{2} =
a_{12\bar{1}\bar{2}}e^{\eta_{1}+\bar{\eta}_{1}+\eta_{2}+\bar{\eta}_{2}},
\\
&& a_{ij\bar{k}} = a_{ij} a_{i\bar{k}} a_{j\bar{k}}, \quad
a_{ij\bar{k}\bar{l}} = a_{ij} a_{i\bar{k}} a_{i\bar{l}} a_{j\bar{k}}
a_{j\bar{l}} a_{\bar{k}\bar{l}}, \\
&&a_{ij} = (p_{i}-p_{j})^{2}, \; a_{i\bar{j}} =
\frac{(p_{i}\bar{p}_{j})^{2}}{(p_{i}+\bar{p}_{j})^{2}}, \;
a_{\bar{i}\bar{j}} = (p_{i}-\bar{p}_{j})^{2}
\end{eqnarray}
where $\eta_{i} = p_{i}^{-1}x + p_{i}t,\; i=1,\;2$. Asymptotic form
of equation (1):
\begin{equation}
\frac{p_{1R}}{|p_{1}|^{2}}\textrm{sech}\left(\frac{\eta_{1}+\bar{\eta}_{1}+\theta_{11}}{2}\right)
\; \eta_{2R}\rightarrow \infty \; \eta_{1} \sim O(1)
\end{equation}
with
$e^{\theta_{11}}=a_{11}a_{1\bar{1}}a_{1\bar{2}}a_{2\bar{1}}a_{\bar{1}\bar{2}}$.

Comment: Hi Riaz: It's generally considered pretty rude at MSE to get an answer to your question, and then change the question so that the answers are no longer valid. If you're still interested in the modified version, please ask a new question. In the mean time, I've reverted your edit. You can view the old version in the edit history (just above this comment), so you won't have to type it all out again :P

Answer (score 1):

If $k=a+ib $, then
\begin{align}
e^{ik}
&=e^{ia-b}\\
&=e^{-b}(\cos (a)+i\sin (a))
\end{align}
hence the limit doesn't exists for $a\to\pm\infty $.

Comment: @ Fabio, if the limit do not exist, then how the answer can be obtained as described above

Answer (score 0):

Let $k=x+iy$ with $x,y \in \mathbb R$. Then $e^{ik}=e^{ix}e^{-y}$

Let $x_n:=n \pi$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. Then $e^{i x_n}=(-1)^n=e^{- ix_n}$.

This shows that the limits in question do not exist.

Comment: @ Fred, if the limit do not exist, then how the answer can be obtained as described above